# API testing with RestAssured

Tags: rest-assured

I am trying to do validation with the following  but getting error "null". when I tried to get the location I Can not travel to location "lat": -33.8585416.

```
{
   "html_attributions": [],
   "results": [
      {
         "geometry": {
            "location": {
               "lat": -33.8585416,
               "lng": 151.2100441
            },
```

I have following script in java:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class BasicAPI {



@Test
    public void nearByApi(){

        RestAssured.baseURI= "https://maps.googleapis.com";

        given().

            param("location","-33.8670522,151.1957362").
            param("radius","1500").
            param("key","AIzaSyAPKUY3YgFBlyyQxjh9q9RQ5cDFdDjqlz4").



when().

        get("/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json").

            then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.JSON).and().          
            body("results[0].geometry.location.lat",equalTo("-33.8670522"));
```

}

}

Keep getting following error:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\PC1\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1596052068\testng-customsuite.xml

[Utils] Attempting to create C:\SampleFramworkFiles\DemoApi\test-output\Default suite\Default test.xml
[Utils]   Directory C:\SampleFramworkFiles\DemoApi\test-output\Default suite exists: true
FAILED: nearByApi
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path results[0].geometry.location.lat doesn't match.
Expected: -33.8670522
  Actual: null
```

Comment: Please provide the complete Json...

Comment: First are you sure you sure that you are getting the JSON content in the response. `JSON path results[0].geometry.location.lat doesn't match.` is seen even if there is no response. Pls check that first.